# VB6 random double overflow errors

Tags: vb6

does anyone know a cause for random overflow errors in vb6?

I have to customize a legacy application written in VB6 and lately overflow errors have started to occur all over the place. Sometimes in functions which have not been touched in years!

The error always happens when trying to assign something to a variable of type Double.

The reason for those errors is probably not the code that throws the error but something else. But I dont know what to look for. The most confusing example of a function failing with an overflow error was the following code:

```
Dim test As Double
test = 0#
```

How can that possibly throw an overflow error?

I tried enabling some compiler optimizations, like not checking for floating point calculation errors, and some more. This has "solved" some of the problems, but others remain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB6 will run things in such a way where if something external signals a floating-point error flag, it'll not be reported until the next floating-point operation is performed within your own code.

Under most circumstances, this is likely caused by some DLL that is performing floating-point operation.  If you have any control over these external DLLs, then my suggestion is to put this line at the end of the functions called by your application:

```
_clearfp();
```

This function is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49bs2z07.aspx

If you do not have much control, you can get around this by making your own function called from a DLL that calls that function.  Or a simple hack with only using VB6 is:

```
Public Sub ClearFP()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim d as Double
    d = 0#
End Sub
```

Which you can call after any DLL calls that you believe is the culprit.

A trick to isolating which function did it originally, is simply look at the calls before the error appears.  Alternatively, a more complicated solution, is to compile your application and run it through a debugger that can break on floating-point exceptions.

Comment: That sounds like a solution to my problem, the only thing that I have changed in the software is replacing a third party component by a newer version.

Comment: Yep.  That's very likely the issue then :).  Accept my answer if it ends up working out!

Comment: Just one more question. The VB hack you posted doesn't work, the next floating point operation still throws an error, do you have any other idea what I can do to recover from such an external error?

Comment: My suggestion of making a C++ DLL that can be called from VB6 that does the _clearfp(); will likely work better than my untested hack.

Comment: Is it possible to call _clearfp from a VB6 `Declare Function` ?

Comment: @DaveInCaz The solution I came up with allows me to call a math library that causes floating point errors to get produced (regardless of floating point precision MSVC project setting).  There is no built-in Win32 API way of doing this unfortunately, so you'd have to make your own DLL that calls this C++ function. This tutorial covers it well: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6243/Step-by-Step-Calling-C-DLLs-from-VC-and-VB-Part-2 (essentially, create a C++ project with a .def file naming functions you'd like to expose - and making sure to define those functions with `__stdcall`).

Answer (score -1):

In VB6 the hash (#) symbol can mean many things:

Used in file names
used with dates ususlly when applied to DBs
To treat Numbers as Doubles
To compile constants or sections of code if a condition is true

I'm sure there are more.

It may depend on the compiler.

My suggestion would be to try:

```
Dim test As Double
test = CDbl(0)
```

to see if that resolves the issue.